# Positioning a absolute div in cienter of screen using jquery - does not work with firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

i am trying to position an element in center of a screen, i am able to achieve it on chrome and safari but on firefox the jquery positioning does not happen unless i resize the window
my jquery script is like this:

```
$(window).on('ready resize', function(){
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  var lopos = $('.banner1').children('img').height()/2;
  var centerPos = $('.banner1').children('img').width()/2;
  var sponsor_place_width = $('#s_place').width();
  $('.logo').children('img').css('top', lopos);
  $('.sponsor_place').css('top', lopos - $('#s_place').outerHeight()/2 +$(document).scrollTop());
  $('.sponsor_place').css('left', centerPos/2);
});
```

is there a way to solve this problem on firefox?

Comment: maybe you could trigger resize: `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: normally you wait for `document` `ready`, not `window` `ready` (using `$(document).ready(...)`, not `$(document).on("ready",...)`). Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$(window).height()` is sensitive to doctype. Try `<!doctype html>`.
 are you using jquery 1.8 and firefox below 16?

alert the value of `$(window).height()` in firefox 
use

`$('#s_place').outerHeight({margin: true})`;  and alert this also in all browser

Comment: i am using jquery-2.0.0 and firefox 21.0

Comment: alert the $(window).height() value

Comment: $(window).height() value is 716 in firefox, 612 in chrome and 596in safari. and $('#s_place').outerHeight() is 0 in firefox and 4 in both safari and chrome i think this is a place where problem is.

Comment: $('#s_place').outerHeight({margin: true}); use this and then alert the value

Answer (score 1):

```
.center
{
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

add the class center for the image tag which you want in the center.